# Visual Studio 2022 MAUI + Android + SQL Server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022, maui

Hello I'm new on MAUI and C# and , I want to make and Android and Windows app that connect to a SQL Server and INSERT some rows and do some SELECT.

Is there an easy example?

Thanks

Comment: Mobile device applications (Android, iOS) **do not** connect directly to database servers like MSSQL/MySQL/Postgres, instead they typically access data via web-services ("web APIs").

Comment: Hello,Yes but Android Studio allow to connect and work with SQL server... So on MAUI my Windows and Android app always need to use a webservices.?? In that case, any example to develop a simple webservice something that received the SQL query from de app, run against the SQL database and return the result? iLike the server acts as a proxy between the Maui app and the SQL server? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect SQL Server with .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778682/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-net-maui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In that case, any example to develop a simple webservice something

For this, you can check document :[Write a web service by using Visual C# .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/write-web-service).

This article helps you write a web service, called `MathService`, that exposes methods for adding, subtracting, dividing, and multiplying two numbers.

And you can find many tutorials in your browser by entering keywords `How to Develop a RESTful Web Service in ASP.NET Web API`.

For how to communicate with different web services in maui, you can check document : [Consume a REST-based web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/rest) .

Comment: Hi, ok thanks to all for the help, I'm going to read about the webservice REST. Thanks